# How to use 'sort' in Bash to sort a two-field output numerically and alphabetically (in reverse)?

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm having some difficulties performing sorting using Bash's `sort`. My goal is that I want to first sort everything by the number in the first column, with the highest value first. If there are any ties, then I want to look at the second column, and sort in reverse alphabetical order (with respect to ascii values, so for example, in ascii values, `a` comes after `B`, but I'd like the sorting to have `a` come first, before `B`).

My current sorting attempt is `sort -t : -k 1,1nr -k 2.1,2.1` If I have the case where there is a numerical tie in the first column (e.g., both numbers are 5), and if the second column has two different strings where one starts with a lowercase, and the other an uppercase (e.g., `apple` vs. `Orange`), then it'll do the ordering in reverse alphabetical order as I want it to:

```
5 apple
5 Orange
```

However, if there is a numerical tie in the first column, and in the second column both strings start with capital letters, such as `'Apple'` vs. `'Orange'`, in this case it won't reverse the alphabetical order. I would get:

```
5 Apple

5 Orange
```

whereas what I want, with the reversed alphabetical order like in the first example, is:

```
5 Orange

5 Apple
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `bash` sort? Here `bash` has nothing to do.

Comment: Wasn't sure how else to tag it since there isn't a tag for the sort function itself and it's about using this sort within a Bash script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `r` for both the columns. Use `2,2` as the secondary position, you want to start sorting in column 2 and end in column 2, as well. Also, turn off locale that may change how strings are sorted.

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -k1,1nr -k2,2r
```