# Natural sorting in reverse?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to sort a text file in this manner:

```
6 aaa
4 bbb
2 ccc
2 ddd
```

That is, each line sorted first in numeric descending order (the number indicates the number of occurrences of the word on the right), and if multiple words are repeated the same number of times, I'd like to have those words sorted alphabetically.

What I have:

```
6 aaa
4 bbb
2 ddd
2 ccc
```

When I try `sort -nr | sort -V` it kind of does what I want but in ascending order.

```
2 ccc
2 ddd
4 bbb
6 aaa
```

What's a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Avoid chaining `sort`s together. The last one will undo the earlier ones. Use multiple `-k`'s instead.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Many implementations have `-s` option to get a stable sort.

Comment: [How to use 'sort' in Bash to sort a two-field output numerically and alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46758622/608639), [Sort data in descending order of first column, for equal values, use second column in ascending order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122390/56041), etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to specify that the numeric reverse sort only applies to the first field:

```
$ sort -k1,1nr file
6 aaa
4 bbb
2 ccc
2 ddd
```

`-k1,1[OPTS]` means that OPTS only apply between the 1st and 1st field. The rest of the line is sorted according to global ordering options. In this case, since no other options were passed, this means the default lexicographic sort.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe using [`tac`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac)? (not a shell expert here, just remembering uni days...

```
sort -nr | sort -V | tac
```

Comment: Yes I tried `tac` but that simply reverses the output, so `ddd` still would come before `ccc`.